# Is there a standard/prefered method for debug logging in a custom Ansible module.

Tags: debugging, logging, module, ansible, trace

I would like to add debug logging to my custom Ansible module such that when the -vvv option is supplied to the ansible-playbook command I see the log messages but otherwise do not.  I don't want the results of the module to be affected by this logging.  In other words, I don't want to write the log messages to stdout or stderr directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modules normally are executed remotely, so there actually is no way to directly output anything.

You can return additional data in your module in the `exit_json` call.

```
if module._verbosity >= 3:
    module.exit_json(changed=True, debug="wooha!")
else:
    module.exit_json(changed=True)
```

`module._verbosity` corresponds to the verbosity level (-v = 1, -vvv = 3) and is available since Ansible 2.1.

Source: [Ansible Devel-list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ansible-devel/s0iSb7phnqY/UB9vaLFJAwAJ) and [github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/5760f0effbebe55e7150eb06e9a6b691a0e98455#diff-90085fdcec6ed8b273ba885eaee60328)

Answer (score 2):

Ansible module are hard to debug because:

- modules are normally executed remotely
- modules are executed by python subprocess (so we can not use `pdb` to debug)

So, you can debug the Ansible module in this way:

1. **Make the module execute locally.** This can be implemented either by setting the hosts to localhost or by using Ansible `local_action` module.
2. **Write/Logging the variables you want to debug into a specific file.** You can do this by using Python [q](https://github.com/zestyping/q) library.